# Can I NAT multiple Linux clients through a Windows VPN client to a remote network?

Tags: vpn, checkpoint

Here's the situation:

My org has a Check Point firewall.  I can only connect to it using Windows, despite making attempts with Openswan.  Is there a way I can use the Windows box to VPN into my org and then use the Windows box to NAT other local workstations into the remote network?  It seems like I might be able to but I'd like to know that for sure from a networking expert before I run down another rabbit hole.  :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you could probably just enable Internet Connection Sharing on your XP or Vista client ... the situation isn't much different from using one PC to share an internet connection.  Check out MSDN's info on [NAT with ICS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457077.aspx) for more info.

Somewhat more complex is setting up XP routing (which internally might actually be the same thing as ICS).  I did this a few years ago when we were using OpenVPN internally, and followed [these instructions](http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2006-09/msg00031.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have never done it, but I have seen people setup a "gateway" windows box that has the checkpoint client installed, and then have that windows "Gateway" setup to do port forwarding of all their specifically desired ports (22, 21, 3389) to that remote network.  Looks like this site has a [nice tutorial on it](http://www.hackernotcracker.com/2006-03/port-opening-and-forwarding-on-windows-xp.html)